# Qt4 Widget: implementing a wait function without blocking the widget

Tags: c++, user-interface, qt4, widget, wait

I'm writing a simple game in C++ using the (awesome) Qt4 libraries. For a while now, I'm having trouble with the following:

The widget provides (among others) 2 methods, that change the way the widget responds to user input like mouse-movement an clicks etc. Let's call these functions `fun1()` and `fun2()` to avoid context. All these functions do, is toggle some internal variables in the widget which are checked by all the event-functions (e.g. `mouseMoveEvent()`). When `fun1()` is called, the user is expected to perform a move by interacting with the widget and clicking somewhere. The widget checks whether his move was valid and if so, applies his move to the current gamestate.

Now, the main class containing this widget at some point calls `fun1()` and `fun2()` subsequently. I have to implement something (elegant) to ensure that the main loop sits around at the end of `fun1()` until the move has been completed.

```
void Widget::fun1()
{
    // Set some members in order to tell the Widget how to respond to events
    // ...
    wait(); // wait for the move to be completed before returning from fun1()
}
```

How should `wait()` be implemented whilst maintaining the responsiveness of the GUI, i.e. whilst responding to user interaction?

In the past, I resolved this issue by letting the widget's parent wait for the widget to emit a signal that notifies it has finished. Only when this signal was recieved did I call `fun2()`. Though this might work fine, it bothers me that it makes the act of waiting the responsibility of the class using the widget instead of the widget itself.

Any suggestions would be very helpful!

Comment: signals and slots are the way to go. If you implement the Widget class yourself, why not having it implement the slot, signal and connection all within, without involving the parent ?

Comment: @SirDarius Could you elaborate? What would the signal be connected to? How can I make `fun1()` stall in `wait()` while still responding to events?

Comment: actually there would not be such a thing as `wait`. In `fun1()` you perform the connect between your signal and slot (which can be `fun2`). Then the user performs the needed action within the widget, probably detected via other signals, and when the conditions are met, emit your signal, and `fun2` will be called. You can then destroy the connection.

Comment: @SirDarius Ah I see what you mean! But what if I don't always want to call `fun2()` after the action has been performed? Whether or not this is necessary is decided by the parent...

Comment: then the widget must present a method like `enableCallFun2(bool)` that would be called by the parent

Comment: @SirDarius Yeah I guess that should work... Seems like more of a workaround than a solution but nevertheless thanks very much for your help! Appreciate it :-)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me apologize for answering my own question. It turns out that the solutions that I had already tried *did* work, but that I stupidly called `fun1()` and `fun2()` from the constructor of the main window. Therefore, `app.exec()` was never called because of the waiting-function and events were not handled.

The working implementation of `wait()` for those interested is:

```
void Widget::wait()
{
    static QEventLoop loop;
    connect(this, SIGNAL(done()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));
    loop.exec();
}
```